# Bull rushing into a wall

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What happens when the space behind someone is already occupied by a wall? Do they take damage, fall prone, does it not work etc.?

Comment: The wall wins...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Usual Rule

It counts as a successful Bull Rush for the purposes of any abilities that care about things like that, but they do not move.

#### Shock Trooper

This feat from *Complete Warrior*, most famous for its ability to allow you to apply Power Attack penalties to your AC instead of Attack during a charge, also allows you to move foes that you Bull Rush to the side, as well as forward. So if they’re against a wall, this could allow you to move them along the wall.

It also allows you to Bull Rush one enemy into another, knocking both Prone.

#### Dungeoncrasher

The Dungeoncrasher ACF from *Dungeonscape* allows a Fighter to do *sizeable* damage (8d6+3×Str) with this maneuver. This is so reliable and potent that this ACF alone is enough to push the Fighter up a Tier.

Comment: can we assume the same is true if instead of the wall it is another person?

Comment: Also, can u cite the source of your "normal rule" I don't see that spelled out anywhere...if we're inferring from lack of explicit rules &/or utilizing similar rules for other maneuvers (ie tumble) that's fine too just please state that too. Thx

Comment: @Ben-Jamin There simply is no requirement that you cannot initiate a bull rush if there isn’t room for the target to move (Pathfinder actually added such a rule, though it’s still unclear if that means you’re not even allowed to *try*). But since they cannot move into the only square the bull rush can push them into, they don’t move at all. As for another person rather than a wall, no, I think they would move. You can enter other creature’s squares, after all, so you can also be shoved into them.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin PHB 148 has rules on 'Accidentally Ending Movement in an Illegal Space' and it seems to support KRyan's claim.